# How do I backpedal?

Tags: support

[So I asked a question the other day regarding the writing on tombstones in Terraria.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132880/how-do-i-write-on-gravestones) I did my homework, laid out steps to reproduce my issue, however it appeared to be a one-off issue and I no longer see the issue anymore.

Since it is obvious that this question is void of any value to anyone else on this site, do I want to delete the question or just vote to close it?

Comment: Answer it? Someone else might come across the same bug

Comment: Agree.  I've had derp moments before (not saying yours is a derp moment) where the best option is simply to answer the question.

Comment: If you feel it the issue was just a mistake on your part, delete it.  It will not likely help anyone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can't reproduce the steps you took to encounter the bug or fix it, I'd delete the question. If you know *why* you made the mistake (even if it's just I'M SO STUPID I HIT THE WRONG BUTTON), a self answer can make the question useful to others in the future.

Either way, voting to close is pointless. Just unilaterally delete it, or post an answer.